service docker with portainer and traelik
version: "3.7"

services:
  flaskapp:
    image: rainergarcia/flaskapp:1.0
    container_name: flaskapp
    volumes:
      - app_volume:./app_volume
    networks:
      - redmasiva
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.docker.network=redmasiva"
      - "traefik.http.routers.flaskapp.rule=Host(`flaskapp.one.ooxen.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.flaskapp.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.routers.flaskapp.priority=1"
      - "traefik.http.routers.flaskapp.tls.certresolver=letsencryptresolver"
      - "traefik.http.routers.flaskapp.service=flaskapp"
      - "traefik.http.services.flaskapp.loadbalancer.server.port=7000"

networks:
  redmasiva:
    external: true
    attachable: true
    name: redmasiva

volumes:
  app_volume:
    external: true
    name: app_volume

I have this docker compose but when I deploy, exit reject, it does not create the container, Trafik does not detect it, what error will I have?
The other services are Trafik, Portainer and Portainer/agent, each with its own domain and they work well

How are you deploying it? Are you running a docker swarm?


Are you accessing the site with http(s)://flaskapp.one.ooxen.com:7000? Is the port 7000 open on your host, not blocked by firewall? 2. What happens if you remove this line: traefik.http.services.flaskapp.loadbalancer.server.port=7000 or change it to traefik.http.services.flaskapp.loadbalancer.server.port=443 and access the site with https://flaskapp.one.ooxen.com or to traefik.http.services.flaskapp.loadbalancer.server.port=80 and access with http://flaskapp.one.ooxen.com? 3. See what messages are in the logs and post them here (enable debug mode): docker logs -f flaskapp?

